# Vue.js + Element UI: Content editable on el-table's rows

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I need an **editable datagrid** on an application written with **Element UI**.
Actually, I've a table like the following:

```
<el-table :data="myData" stripe="stripe">
    <el-table-column prop="col1" label="Col 1"></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="col2" label="Col 2"></el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

That's rendered in **html** like (simplifying):

```
<table class="el-table__body">
    <td class="el-table_1_column_1">
        <div class="cell">Val col 1</div>
    </td>
    <td class="el-table_1_column_1">
        <div class="cell">Val col 1</div>
    </td>
</table>
```

So, I'd like to append the attribute `contenteditable="true"` to the div with `class="cell"`.
I tried to append the attribute to the `el-table-column` element, but it didn't works.

```
<el-table-column prop="position" label="Pos." contenteditable="true"></el-table-column>
```

Then, how could I make some el-table's cell editable?
Is the `contenteditable` attribute the right way? How can I use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I solved adding a `template` inside any column, each one can access to the parent `scope` specifying the attribute `slot-scope="scope"`. In this way, the inner input can be bounded with the column of each row.

Then, I've implemented my table like following:

```
<el-table :data="myData" stripe="stripe">
    <el-table-column prop="col1" label="Col 1">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            <el-input-number v-model="scope.row.col1" :min="1" :max="99" size="small" controls-position="right" />
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="col2" label="Col 2"></el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

In the above code, the `col1` is bounded with the datasource's table `myData` on `col1`, through the attribute `v-model="scope.row.col1"`.

Obviously, in the template you can insert anything you need: `el-input`, `el-input-number` or even custom components.

Note: You can choose to make editable just some columns, as you can see in the above example (the second column is not editable).

Comment: I ran into the same issue as you, and came to the same conclusion, but my el-input-number step doesn't work when I bind the data from el-table. The number only increments once, and then stops reponding without any errors.  If I switch the v-model to some other variable it works just fine, but it doesn't seem to be able to update the data in scope.row.myvar. Did you have any similar issues?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't have that issue... anyway could you create a new Question here on SO and share your code?

Comment: I figured out my issue... v-model and vuex.